# replace special character python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, floating-point

i have a list of titles come from csv file but some of them have (,a) and i want to remove it to becaome (a) ,and then will add new title to new list but i got error.

CODE:

```
import pandas as pd 
import string

new_title  =[]
alphabests = list(string.ascii_letters) # this list invlude all alphabets
title_file = pd.read_csv('D:\\titles.csv',sep=';')
title      = title_file['title']

x=0 #move in titles
while x < len(title):
    y=0 #move in alphabets
    while y < len(alphabests):
        check_about_alpabets = [w.replace(',{}'.format(alphabests[y]), '{}'.format(alphabests[y])) for w in title[x]]
        y +=1
    new_title.append(title[x])
    x +=1
```

ERROR

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: What is video_file?  Should it be: `title  = title_file['title']`?

Comment: yes, but what is solution

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest two edits that might help you figure out the error:
first, instead of using a while loop, use a for loop, and iterate over the items in the title list.
before trying to tackle the error, try printing out the variables of that list,
there might be a title that is of a Float type - meaning a number, which you cannot iterate over, ( or try to remove special characters).
If there is such a title, try creating two conditions using if statements to work with each type differently, here's what I mean.

```
for x in title: #iterating over the list
    if type(title) == float or type(title) == int:
       #do something
    else:
       #do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

Two improvements can be made to posted code

- Use dataframe apply rather than using Python for or while loop to process each title (i.e. very slow)
- Use regex rather than looping through each letter of the alphabet to check for comma followed by a letter (also slow)

**Code**

```
import re
def clean_title(title): 
  " Expression to clean title "
  # Remove comma when followed by a word letter 
  return re.sub(r',(\w)', lambda m: m.group(1), title)
    
# Clean titles
df['title'] = df['title'].apply(clean_title)
```

**Test**

- Generate dataset--List of Movie titles and year released
- Contains desired and undesired commas in title

Example of Undesired Comma:

- The S,even Samurai

Example of Desired Comma:

- 'I, Tonya'

Create Dataset

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'title':['Lock, Stock and Two Smoking Barrels', 'The S,even Samurai', 'B,onnie and C,lyde', 'Reser,voir Dogs', 'A,irplane!', 'Doct,or Zhiva,go', 'I, Tonya'], 
                    'Year':['1998', '1954', '1967', '1992', '1980', '1965', '2017']})
  
print(df)
```

Dataset Before Cleanup

```
                                title  Year
0  Lock, Stock and Two Smoking Barrels  1998
1                   The S,even Samurai  1954
2                   B,onnie and C,lyde  1967
3                      Reser,voir Dogs  1992
4                           A,irplane!  1980
5                     Doct,or Zhiva,go  1965
6                             I, Tonya  2017
```

Dataset After Cleanup

```
                               title  Year
0  Lock, Stock and Two Smoking Barrels  1998
1                    The Seven Samurai  1954
2                     Bonnie and Clyde  1967
3                       Reservoir Dogs  1992
4                            Airplane!  1980
5                       Doctor Zhivago  1965
6                             I, Tonya  2017
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the variable 'title' is a series object in Pandas and not a list.
If u want to change the column names in your dataframe you can do this:

```
      column_name = list(title_file.columns)
      column_dict = {}
      for name in column_name:
          for char,idx in enumerate(name):
             if char == ',':
                new_name = name[idx+1:])
                column_dict[name] = new_name
      title_file.rename(columns = column_dict, inplace = True)
```

But before setting inplace argument as True just check for the output